# Service with http(s) REST API to sign and verify JWTs

Tags: jwt, microservices, pki, encryption-asymmetric

I have a complex architecture of virtual machines to implement a SaaS.
These nodes interacts with each other (on a backend network) and with the customers (via "The Internet") authenticating their requests using JWTs.

Instead of spreading the private key among all the nodes that need to sign the JWTs and the public key among all the nodes that need to verify the JWTs... I would like to create a simple service that has access to the private and the public key and can accept http rest api request of validate and sign JWT (on the backend network)
For example:

- receives a http `/api/jwt/validate` with a signed jwt in the body -> verifies locally the received jwt against the public key, returns the decoded jwt payload
- receives a http `/api/jwt/sign` with a unsigned jwt in the body -> signs locally the received jwt with the private key, returns the signed jwt

I know that, for example, [FusionAuth](https://fusionauth.io/) does this ... but it does a lot of other things that i don't need.

Noted that I will address all the security issues, is this a good approach?

Do anyone know a opensource project that i can start from to implement this service?